# Would this Op-Amp instrument mixer design work properly?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

After searching for a while about op amp audio mixers, I wanted to design one myself and designed the circuit below. I wanted to have 4 inputs and control the gain and volume for each. I think my circuit would work but I am not sure if I used the correct values for the components and put the volume potentiometers at the right place. I am a little new to electronics so I am sorry if I am asking a question about a horrbile circuit.
[image: Circuit Schematic]

Comment: If by an instrument mixer you mean e.g. electric guitar pickup level signals, then the input impedance of 10k is too low, it usually is in the 1 megaohm region. And in your circuit, the 1 megaohm is quite useless. If you would describe how you came up to design the circuit (i.e. why these components and why arranged like that), it might be easier to understand why it is like it is.

Comment: The 1 Megaohm resistor was to discharge the capacitor so that there would be no other dc voltage bias other than the default 4.5V. I am planning on using it with guitars but I might also use something like a drum machine if that makes any difference.

Comment: The DC feedback through your Gain pots would be more than adequate to keep the inverting inputs properly biased to your mid-supply point. All the 1M resistors would do is introduce a slight bias away from that point.

Comment: Why do you have both an adjustable Gain pot as well as a Volume voltage-divider pot?

Comment: I thought if I wanted to have a crunchy sound, the volume pot wouldn't allow me to do that so I made the gains adjustable. Do you think there would be a reasonable difference using gain control over volume control?

Comment: @SlateDobby Yeah but the 1 Mohm won't charge or discharge the bias because the op-amp already keeps it's negative input at 4.5V so it is quite useless.

Comment: @brhans Guitar amps tend to have a gain pot for the input to cause clipping and distortion etc other effects. Then they have a volume knob how loud the speaker is driven with the whatever clipped/distorted audio waveform.

Comment: @SlateDobby "Crunchy sound" is not something you do with opamps.  They don't do overdrive but only hard clipping.  If you want to do overdrive, you'll likely use a JFET stage or similar, possibly with some RC artistry around it.

Comment: One other thing to note is that your "volume" pots will slightly affect your overall level in addition to the level of the channel they are attached to.  Usually not desirable for a mixer.

Comment: @JohnD where should the volume pots be in the circuit?

Comment: @JohnD No, the volume controls are virtually independent.  It doesn't look like it, but they all connect to a virtual 4.5V on the summing opamp, so any interference will happen at frequencies where the GBW is close to being exhausted.  At lower frequencies, the opamp will provide near zero impedance to the 4.5V summing point.

Comment: @user107063 OK, right, good point, deleted my comment.